# Is net present value of $a_n-b_n$ eventually negative for nonnegative $a_n\to 0,b_n\not\to 0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Suppose $x_n=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \rho^k (a_{n+k}-b_{n+k})$ and $\rho\in (0,1),a_n\geq 0,b_n>0\quad \forall n\geq 0$. Does $a_n\to 0,b_n\not\to 0$ imply $x_n$ is eventually negative?

My initial hunch was affirmative, but I want to be sure.

I have already shown that for generic sequence $z_n$, we have $$z_n \to z\iff \sum_{k=0}^\infty \rho^k z_{n+k}\to z/(1-\rho).$$

So $b_n\not\to 0$ implies $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \rho^k b_{n+k}\not\to 0.$ Hence $\exists \epsilon>0$ s.t. $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \rho^k b_{n+k}>\epsilon$ for infinitely many $n$.

Meanwhile, $a_n\to 0$ implies $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \rho^k a_{n+k}\to 0$ so for some $N$, $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \rho^k a_{n+k}<\epsilon$ for $n\geq N$.

So $x_n$ should be negative infinitely often but can we say it is eventually always negative?

Answer (score 1):

We can't - even if $b_n \not \to 0$, it can have big elements rare enough so that between them $a_n$ dominates.

For example, let $m_t$ be an increasing sequence such that $\frac{1}{2t} \sum\limits_{i=m_t + 1}^{m_{t + 1} - 1} p^i > \sum\limits_{i = m_{t + 1}}^\infty p^i$ (such sequence exists, because on each step right side goes to $0$ when $m_{t + 1}$ increases, while left side is positive and increases).

Let $a_i = \frac{1}{t}$ for $m_t \leq i < m_{t + 1}$, $b_i = \frac{1}{2i}$ for $m_t < i < m_{t + 1}$ and $b_{m_t} = 1$.

Then all conditions are satisfied, but
$$x_{m_t + 1} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty p^k (a_{m_t + 1 + k} - b_{m_t + 1 + k}) = \sum\limits_{i=m_t + 1}^\infty p^i(a_i - b_i) =
\sum_{i=m_t + 1}^{m_{t + 1} - 1} p^i (a_i - b_i) + \sum\limits_{i = m_{t+1}}^\infty p^i (a_i - b_i) \geq\\
\sum\limits_{i=m_{t} - 1}^{m_{t + 1} - 1} p^i \frac{1}{2t} - \sum_{i=m_{t + 1}}^\infty p^i > 0$$